# ExoPlayer is not playing H264 MPEG-4 AVC file on Android?

Tags: android, video, exoplayer, codec

I'm trying to use the ExoPlayer to play an MP4 file. The file has the codec H264 MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)  (avc1). Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
2022-11-02 06:36:15.750 4108-4678/xxx.xxx.xxx D/MediaCodecInfo: NoSupport [codec.profileLevel, avc1.420029, video/avc] [OMX.SEC.avc.sw.dec, video/avc] [gta4lwifi, SM-T500, samsung, 30]
```

When I looked on the ExoPlayer website, I find H264 as a supported format. Do you have any experience/idea, why it does not play the video?

Comment: Can you share a link to the video file or an ffprobe output for the video file - H.264 has multiple options and profiles and it is possible that the particular video using some that are not supported.